# Inherited parameter in lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, lambda

I've got some problems with my lamba expressions: I have a class that owns a function pointer.

```
class SomeClass
{
    void (*execFunc)(Base*);
}
```

And I have a Base class:

```
class Base
{
    SomeClass* someClass;
    void doSomething() { someClass->execFunc(this); }
}
```

From this one I derive lots of other classes whose `execFunc`s will be different. Therefore I want to use lambda-expressions; e.g:

```
class Derived final : public Base
{
    int someDerivedAttrib;

    static List<SomeClass*> someClasses = createSomeClasses();    // holds all possible
                                                                  // SomeClasses for this 
                                                                  // derived class
    static List<SomeClass*> createSomeClasses()
    {
        List<SomeClass*> scs;
        SomeClass* sc = new SomeClass();
        sc->execFunc = [] (Derived* derived) { derived->someDerivedAttrib = 10; };
        scs << sc;
        return scs
    }
 }
```

But unfornately this won't work since cast from `void (*)(Derived*)` to `void (*)(Base*)` is not possible. Any suggestions, except making a cast form `Base*` to `Derived*` in every lambda-function?

Expecting ye answers,
Albjenow

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the actual use scenario for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about, instead of `SomeClass` being a regular class, making it a the base class of a class template that handles having the proper functor type, as well as   downcasting to the right type ?
It would look like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    virtual void callFunc(Base*) = 0;
}

template<typename T>
class SomeDerivedClass : public SomeClass
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "SomeDerivedClass: unexpected base class");
    virtual void callFunc(Base* b) override
    {
         execFunc(static_cast<T*>(b));
    }
    void (*execFunc)(T*);
}
```

`Base` then becomes:

```
class Base
{
    SomeClass* someClass;
    void doSomething() { someClass->callFunc(this); }
}
```

Then, in your `Derived` definition:

```
class Derived final : public Base
{
    int someDerivedAttrib;

    typedef SomeDerivedClass<Derived> tSomeClass;
    static List<tSomeClass*> someClasses = createSomeClasses();    // holds all possible
                                                                  // SomeClasses for this 
                                                                  // derived class
    static List<tSomeClass*> createSomeClasses()
    {
        List<tSomeClass*> scs;
        tSomeClass* sc = new tSomeClass();
        sc->execFunc = [] (Derived* derived) { derived->someDerivedAttrib = 10; };
        scs << sc;
        return scs
    }
}
```

However, this runs the risk of calling `SomeDerivedClass::call` with the wrong concrete class.

Comment: But I need to call the `SomeClass::execFunc`from the base class which holds the pointer to it.

Comment: Exactly what I just thought of, gj, thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do the trick?

```
sc->execFunc = [] (Base* base) { static_cast<Derived*>(base)->someDerivedAttrib = 10;
```

After all you have to respect the original signature of the execFunc pointer.

Comment: From the original question: `Any suggestions, except making a cast form Base* to Derived* in every lambda-function` ?

Comment: Of course it would, but as mentioned before, I'm looking for another strategy since I'm a quite lazy programmer. Otherwise I could also use an expansive if-else statement which evaluates the current SomeClass.